# How can I extract shapes and graphics

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

I want to extract graphics created in word from PDF files. 
Extracting image with iTextSharp is possible but shapes are not detected.

With graphics or shapes like this, all the words or characters are extracted but not the shapes.

[image]

Comment: Please provide a sample PDF, not an image, for inspection. I assume, though, that your *shapes* have been created using path commands (vector graphics) which are not yet handled by the iText parser framework.

Comment: You might have to use something other than iText. There are plenty of other solutions out there if you rephrase your question in terms of a generic problem rather than an iText one.